How do I match the original x86 assembly that's reading two bytes using MOV followed by AND?
I'm decompiling the executable of an old Windows 95 game that has been compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 4.1 or 4.2. For each function I create a "scratch" on decomp.me to try to write C code to match the original assembly.
Fair warning: decomp.me uses the AT&T syntax instead of the Intel one commonly used for x86.
One issue that has been cropping up a lot is that reading two bytes using mov is immediately followed by an and that matches all bits. I interpret this as it reading an unsigned short from a four-byte value (a struct or union of two shorts).
mov     0x4328f8(,%eax,2),%ax
and     $0xffff,%eax

However, using an unsigned value always results in an extra xor, and no and:
xor     %edx,%edx
mov     _DAT_004328f8-0x10(,%eax,2),%dx

If I use a signed value instead, mov turns into movswl. Adding & 0xFFFF doesn't make the expected and appear, either.
movswl  _DAT_004328f8-0x10(,%eax,2),%eax

At this point I'm out of ideas, and others in the community haven't been able to find what's wrong, either. How do I match this scratch? https://decomp.me/scratch/6Nlvk

Wow, I wonder what CPU MSVC thought it was tuning for with that MOV/AND?  Maybe 486 through Pentium, where a movzx load might cost 1 more cycle than mov + and (https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/%7Efpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html), if I-cache misses aren't a problem from the larger code-size.  Oh, but yeah, if you are going to manually emulate movzx, xor-zero + mov is cheaper (even on 486 / Pentium) and smaller code-size.  No sane compiler will generate mov+and, especially not a modern compiler.

Anyway, nothing is wrong.  Do you need to reproduce the original sequence of asm instructions, or is it fine to get the same result a different way?

One difference is that the and code will set flags. Does the subsequent code do anything with them?

The xor version also needs to use two registers, while the and version lets you load and zero extend into the same register that held the address. So what about trying a case where there is more register pressure? Or maybe where the pointer is returned from a function call, and the loaded value will be the return value of this function?

Do you know what compiler options were used by the original code? Have you experimented with compiling your test code with different sets of options?

@PeterCordes It was released in 1995 and 1996, and targeted the Pentium, so you're on the mark. :) I'd like to reproduce the original sequence of instructions so I'm sure my code is correct.

@NateEldredge I have experimented with different compiler versions and options. I don't think the and matters for the flags, because it's soon followed by a sar instruction that also sets flags.

Are you 100% sure what compiler the original was compiled with?  And that's what you're using on https://decomp.me/?  (Interesting, I didn't know there was a compiler-explorer type of site with ancient compilers set up for public use.)  But anyway, Nate makes a good point about needing a separate register for xor-zero / mov; have you tried uint16_t *p = foo(); return *p; so the pointer is in EAX and it also needs to load into EAX?  (Or int idx = foo(); return arr[idx];) That might convince it to use MOV/AND.

@PeterCordes I can't be 100% sure of the compiler used. But it can't be msvc 5 (released 1997) or greater because this version of the game was released in 1996. From testing the assembly generated by msvc 4.1 and 4.2 matches best, so that's what I use on decomp.me.
Feel free to try things on the scratch. I tried the suggestion but then it just uses ecx.

I was able to get that compiler on decomp.me to use mov+and in code that does tmp = arr[idx] / if (... & tmp) return tmp; -  https://decomp.me/scratch/1u9w1  .  It's not the optimal way to compile that; MSVC could have used ECX for the idx before using it for the shift count to allow xor/mov into AX.  So it will use that strategy sometimes, just not for the surrounding code in your specific case.  Both are just 486/Pentium size vs. speed tradeoffs for MOVZX.  Logically equivalent source-code written differently can optimize differently, if for some reason you want to repro that.

@user16316067 The sar uses the sign bit as the shift in bit.

It uses the sign bit of the source operand, but not the sign flag.
